# Is there a way to find the actual size of a form that is resizing itself with AutoSize=true?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Is there a way to find the actual size of a form that is resizing itself with `AutoSize=true`?

For example, I have a form that's creating controllers at runtime, and I want some of the controllers to be placed at certain spots relative to the size of the form.

When I try to get from the form `This.Width` or `This.Right` or `This.PreferredSize.Width` they return values that are too large so I suspect there's some default size to the form that the `AutoSize` doesn't touch.

Is there a way to force the `AutoSize` to update the current size of the form?

Comment: Just wait until the Load event fires, one of the few real reasons to ever use that event.  Forcing it does not get you ahead at all, you cannot get the real size until the native window is created.  And be sure to use the ClientSize property, you have little use for Size if you care about layout since it is still unpredictable.

Comment: @HansPassant by load event you mean the `InitializeComponent()`?

Comment: @kuhaku No, he means the `Load` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Width`, `Height` and `Size` will always return the "actual" size of your form. You can however subscribe to the `SizeChanged` event to be notified of any changes, e.g:

```
public Form1()
{
   this.SizeChanged += Form1_SizeChanged;
   InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(this.Width + "/" + this.Height);
}
```

Or, if you only need it once (after AutoSize), you can use the `Load` event instead:

```
public Form1()
{
    this.Load += Form1_Load;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(this.Width + "/" + this.Height);
}
```

Further info:

[Order of Events in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Form.Load Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Control.SizeChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It's not exactly what I asked about, I asked if after adding controllers to certain locations, and while still initializing the form, to be able to get its size from the autosize. It has nothing to do with the user resizing.